# attritbute error : ArrayStack object has no attribute len()

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is the code:

```
class Empty(Exception):
    pass

class ArrayStack:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = []

    def __len(self):
        return len(self._data)

    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self._data)==0

    def push(self, e):
        self._data.append(e)

    def pop(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise empty('Stack is Empty')
        return self._data.pop()

    def top(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise empty('Stack is Empty')
        return self._data[-1]

s= ArrayStack()
s.push(10)
s.push(20)
print('Stack: ', s._data)
**print('Length: ', len(s)) #this line is throwing the problem**
print('Is-Empty: ', s.is_empty())
print('Popped: ', s.pop())
print('Stack: ', s._data)
```

> error message

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 31, in 
    print('Length: ', s.__len())
AttributeError: 'ArrayStack' object has no attribute '__len'**

Comment: \_\_len() should be \_\_len__(). https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ArrayStack Class 
your method __len() is typo mistake.

Your method should be **len**() because it is a magic method.

```
    def __len__(self):
    return len(self._data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your len definition. It should be __len__. 
I have noticed a second issue. You should capitalize 'empty' raise.

Comment: Didn't understand what you are referring to, kindly explain!

Comment: As answered by Rushikesh Sabde you have a typo. A second issue is related to raise empty('Stack is Empty'). It has to be raise Empty('Stack is Empty'). Your object is not "empty" but "Empty".